# How to get the last index in a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++17, mql4, mql5

i am coding in a language similar to c++ known as mql5.(for mt5 trading platform) they have many similarities... i have a for loop as shown below:

```
void OnTick()  // this functon basically executes the code after every price change.
{
   for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)  //the for loop function
    {
     Print(i);  //this prints the loop
    }
}
```

the result of the code above with each price change overtime is:

```
13:27:18.706    0
13:27:18.706    1
13:27:18.706    2
13:27:18.706    3
13:27:18.706    4

13:27:18.900    0
13:27:18.900    1
13:27:18.900    2
13:27:18.900    3
13:27:18.900    4
```

question is, how do i access the last element in the index of the for loop and get it to print 4th index each time price changes? mql5 is somewhat similar as c++. is there anything i can carry from c++?

eg

```
13:27:18.706    4
13:27:18.900    4
```

Comment: It's not possible to access `i` outside of the loops scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is pull `i` outside the loop:

```cpp
void OnTick()
{
   int i = 0;
   for (; i < 5; i++)
   {
     Print(i);
   }
   // i is now one past the last index
   int last = i - 1;
}
```

If you know that you loop `5` times in advance, you could also obtain the last index using:

```cpp
int last = 5 - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use magic numbers. `5` is a magic number. Give it a meaningful name, like `number_of_prices`.

```
constexpr size_t number_of_prices = 5;

void OnTick()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_prices; ++i)  //the for loop function
    {
        Print(i);  //this prints the loop
    }
    Print(number_of_prices - 1); // access last price
}
```